# Links from BeautifulSoup without href or <a>

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a bot that scrapes all the image links from a site and store them somewhere else so I can download the images after.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs  
import requests

url = 'https://www.artstation.com/artwork?sorting=trending'
page = requests.get(url)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
gallery =  soup.find_all(class_="image-src")
data = gallery[0]
for x in range(len(gallery)):
    print("TAG:", sep="\n")
    print(gallery[x], sep="\n")

if page.status_code == 200:  
    print("Request OK")
```

This returns all the links tags i wanted but I can't find a way to remove the html or copy only the links to a new list. Here is an example of the tag i get:

```
<div class="image-src" image-src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/012/269/255/20180810092820/smaller_square/vince-rizzi-batman-n52-p1-a.jpg?1533911301" ng-if="::!project.hide_as_adult"></div>
```

So, how do i get only the links within the gallery[] list? 
What i want to do after is to take this links and edit the /smaller-square/ directory to /large/, which is the one that has the high resolution image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page loads it's data through AJAX, so through network inspector we see, where the call is made. This snippet will obtain all the image links found on page `1`, sorted by `trending`:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.artstation.com/projects.json?page=1&sorting=trending'
page = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(page.text)

for data in json_data['data']:
    print(data['cover']['medium_image_url'])
```

Prints:

```
https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/012/272/796/medium/ben-zhang-brigitte-hero-concept.jpg?1533921480
https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/covers/images/012/279/572/medium/ham-sung-choul-braveking-140823-1-3-s3-mini.jpg?1533959982
https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/covers/images/012/275/963/medium/michael-vicente-orb-gem-thumb.jpg?1533933774
https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/012/275/635/medium/michael-kutsche-piglet-by-michael-kutsche.jpg?1533932387
https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/012/273/384/medium/ben-zhang-unnamed.jpg?1533923353
https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/covers/images/012/273/083/medium/michael-vicente-orb-guardian-thumb.jpg?1533922229

... and so on.
```

If you print the variable `json_data`, you will see other information the page sends (like icon image url, total_count, data about the author etc.)

Comment: This is actually really helpful! I will be experimenting a lot with this information now. Maybe i should have learned how to take more info about the site before trying things. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to your response I managed to download all the images from that page! It was really a awesome solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the attributes using key-value.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''<div class="image-src" image-src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/012/269/255/20180810092820/smaller_square/vince-rizzi-batman-n52-p1-a.jpg?1533911301" ng-if="::!project.hide_as_adult"></div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", class_="image-src")["image-src"])
#or
print(soup.find("div", class_="image-src").attrs['image-src'])
```

**Output:**

```
https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/012/269/255/20180810092820/smaller_square/vince-rizzi-batman-n52-p1-a.jpg?1533911301
```